# Retrieving values trimmed by ltrim in redis list

Tags: python, redis

A common design pattern in redis when handling lists is:

```
redis_server.lpush(list_name, element)
redis_server.ltrim(list_name, 0, 99)
```

(used python syntax to illustate it)

What to do if one needs to retrieve all the values beyond index 99, before invoking `ltrim`? One way to do it is as follows, but is there a *faster* way to do it?

---

```
redis_server.lpush(list_name, element)
list_length = redis_server.llen(list_name)
extra = list_length - 100
while (extra > 0):
    item = redis_server.lpop(list_name)
    #do something with the item
    extra = extra - 1
redis_server.ltrim(list_name, 0, 99)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first solution would be to get all extra items in one request, using [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange):

```
redis_server.lpush(list_name, element)
items = redis_server.lrange(list_name, 100, -1)
# do something with the items
redis_server.ltrim(list_name, 0, 99)
```

A second solution, a bit more complex but *maybe* faster (would need to be confirmed by a test, it's not certain) as it requires only one request instead of two, would be to write a Lua script and to send it using [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval) and [EVALSHA](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha). But you probably don't need it, the first is certainly fast enough.

Comment: lrange list_name 100 -1

Comment: What happens if start and end indices passed to lrange are out of range? No need to put this in `try` and `except`?

Comment: From LRANGE's doc: "Out of range indexes will not produce an error. If start is larger than the end of the list, an empty list is returned. If stop is larger than the actual end of the list, Redis will treat it like the last element of the list.". LTRIM won't produce an error neither.